# How to connect Delphi to SQL Server CE 4.0?

Tags: delphi, sql-server-ce, delphi-xe2, sql-server-ce-4

Installed 64-bit version of the SQL Server CE 4.0. By using SQL Server Management Studio has created a `.sdf` file of database. How to connect from Delphi XE to that database?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I'd like to ask you [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) :)

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Devart UniDAC to connect to SQL Server CE files. I tried it and it works!

Comment: This  is not an answer to the question asked, and shouldn't be posted as one. It's a recommendation for a third-party library. It's at best a comment to the original question.